# convert string of letters in a list to digits

Tags: python

I have read a file into a list which looks like this:

```
['>chr1_sliding:1-1000\n', 'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTATCATCGACTAGAGGCTCATAAACCTCACCCCACATATGTTTCCTTGCCATAGATTACATTCTTGGATTTCTGGTGGAAACCAT\n', '\n', '>chr1_sliding:901-1900\n', 'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTAT....]
```

I want to convert the letters to numbers based on this dictionary:

```
dict = {"A": 0, "T": 1,"G": 2, "C": 3}
```

I have done this:

```
with open("/Users/Downloads/test") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line)

for line in lines:
    try:
        print(dict[line])
    except KeyError:
        print("header")
```

However I get "header" printed every line:

#### Output

```
header
header 
header
header
```

#### Expected output:

```
header
13012...
header
13012...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I get header every line" ? Can you post your output and the expected output?

Comment: You loop through the lines but not through the characters in each line

Comment: Can you share a sample output of the file that you want to save?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal he is literally printing `header` for a `KeyError`

Comment: You need to loop through every **char** in the line, not the lines

Comment: also `dict` is a reserved keyword in python, so you better rename your dict ;)

Comment: You get "header" every time because when you do `print(dict[line])`, here, `line` is the whole string `'TCATGGCTAT ...`, and of course you cannot find it as a key in your dictionary. BTW, change the name `dict`, it is a reserved word in Python.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off by defining a transform function which will transform a given line as per the rules:

```
def transformData(line):
    transform_dict = {"A": 0, "T": 1, "G": 2, "C": 3}

    for char, val in transform_dict.items():
        line = line.replace(char, str(val))

    return line
```

Then proceed to iterating through each line and check if it's a valid line to be transformed. If it is a valid line pass it to the transform function and store the result.

```
data = ['>chr1_sliding:1-1000\n', 'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTATCATCGACTAGAGGCTCATAAACCTCACCCCACATATGTTTCCTTGCCATAGATTACATTCTTGGATTTCTGGTGGAAACCAT\n', '\n', '>chr1_sliding:901-1900\n', 'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTAT....\n']

headers = []    # For storing the final transformed data

for line in data:
    if not line.startswith('>') and line.strip():    # Check if a given line is valid
        headers.append(transformData(line))          # Transform the line and store it
```

Finally print out the result the way you intend to:

```
for line in headers:
    print('header', line, sep='\n')
```

#### Output

---

```
header
13012...
header
13012...
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in transformData
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini I have updated the function `transformData`

Answer (score 1):

How about looping over the list and checking if you have a string with all caps and then converting it via the dict?

Here's how:

```
lines = [
    '>chr1_sliding:1-1000\n',
    'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTATCATCGACTAGAGGCTCATAAACCTCACCCCACATATGTTTCCTTGCCATAGATTACATTCTTGGATTTCTGGTGGAAACCAT\n',
    '\n',
    '>chr1_sliding:901-1900\n',
    'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTAT',
]
d = {"A": 0, "T": 1, "G": 2, "C": 3}

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.isupper():
        print("".join(str(d[ch]) for ch in line), end="")
    else:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
>chr1_sliding:1-1000
130122310111130100000012222211212122330111013013203102022313010003313033330301012111331123301020110301131122011131221220003301
>chr1_sliding:901-1900
13012231011113010000001222221121212233011101
```

Answer (score 0):

your dictionary has characters as keys, not lines.

```py
for line in lines:
    for char in line:
        print(dict.get(char, char))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution for replacing:

```
d = {"A": 0, "T": 1, "G": 2, "C": 3}
s = 'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTAT'

for key, val in d.items():
    strval = str(val)
    s = s.replace(key, strval)
```

Comment: Nice approach! You just need to do that only to the specific lines. And `val` must be a string

Comment: @Tomerikoo : Yes, I already mentioned that this is only the code for replacing. You are right concerning the string, I corrected.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can upgrade the solution of baduker by using startswith method:
Example

```
lines = ['>chr1_sliding:1-1000\n',
'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTATCATCGACTAGAGGCTCATAAACCTCACCCCACATATGTTTCCTTGCCATAGATTACATTCTTGGATTTCTGGTGGAAACCAT\n',
     '\n', '>chr1_sliding:901-1900\n', 'TCATGGCTATTTTCATAAAAAATGGGGGTTGTGTGGCCATTTAT']
d = {"A": 0, "T": 1, "G": 2, "C": 3}

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line and not line.startswith(">chr1_sliding"):
        print(f"header {''.join(str(d[ch]) for ch in line)}")
```

Comment: Also you have undefined `lines`. If you're copy-pasting someone's solution, do it like a man.

Comment: Also to avoid the `str(d[ch])` you can just initialize the dict with strings: `d = {'A': '0', ...}`

Answer (score -2):

Why are you going outside the `with open` it can be done while being inside it.

```
with open("/Users/Downloads/test") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        for char in line:
            try:
                print(dict[char])
            except KeyError:
                print("header")
```